# AjaxControlToolkit.CommonToolkitScripts error

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I got following code in my asp.net application

```
 <aspext:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
      <Scripts>
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.Common.Common.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
           <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderBase.BaseScripts.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </Scripts>
 </aspext:ToolkitScriptManager>
 <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" />

 <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
      function getPosition() {
           //alert( $common.getLocation($get("<%=Panel1.ClientID %>")).x);
           var commonObj = new AjaxControlToolkit._CommonToolkitScripts();
           $common.setBounds($get("<%=Panel1.ClientID %>"),
           {
                x : 100,
                y : 200,
                width : 200,
                height : 100
           }
      }
 </script>
```

but I am getting this error:

```
The assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'AjaxControlToolkit.Common.Common.js'. Make sure that the resource name is spelled correctly. Make sure that the application references the correct version of an ASP.NET AJAX Framework assembly
```

how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using this code, use `ScriptManager` instead of `ToolkitScriptManager`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.Common.Common.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderBase.BaseScripts.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
            </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

In reference to [asp.net forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1228497.aspx)

Comment: I used it and got: The assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit, Version=4.1.40412.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e' does not contain a Web resource that has the name 'AjaxControlToolkit.Common.Common.js'. Make sure that the resource name is spelled correctly. Make sure that the application references the correct version of an ASP.NET AJAX Framework assembly.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Try `<CompositeScript><Scripts> /* .. */ </Scripts></CompositeScript>` tag. In reference to http://www.asp.net/downloads/35-sp1/readme#_Toc198012546

Comment: @Harsh: I used it but same error.   <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        <CompositeScript>
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.Common.Common.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderBase.BaseScripts.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
            </Scripts>
        </CompositeScript>
    </asp:ScriptManager>

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Hey the above Scripts are for .NET 3.5 sp1 as the link http://www.asp.net/downloads/35-sp1/readme#_Toc198012546 states and you are using .NET Framework 4, I think that might be problem with this.

Comment: @DotnetSparrow Also check the version of `AjaxControlToolkit.dll`, it `should be 3.5` or more and `not 1.0`