# AjaxToolKit AutoComplete Extender is Just Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocomplete, autocompleteextender

So I have spent 4 days now researching and trying everything I can find on StackOverflow and other sites. And I just can't get my Ajax AutoCompleteExtender to work. I am using VS 2012 and ASP.NET and C# building for .NET 4.5
Here is my code:

~/Dashboard/Default.aspx

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

   <%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolKit" %>

   <ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
       <Services>
           <asp:ServiceReference Path="~/Dashboard/AutoComplete2.asmx" />
       </Services>
   </ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager>


   <asp:TextBox ID="CarMake_TextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

   <ajaxToolKit:AutoCompleteExtender 
       ID="CarMake_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server"
       Enabled="true"
       ServicePath="AutoComplete2.asmx"
       ServiceMethod="GetCarMakeList"
       TargetControlID="CarMake_TextBox"
       MinimumPrefixLength="1" FirstRowSelected="True"
       >
   </ajaxToolKit:AutoCompleteExtender>

</asp:Content>
```

~/Dashboard/AutoComplete2.asmx.cs  (C#)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace CDC.Dashboard
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AutoComplete2
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://websiteleaders.com/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line.
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AutoComplete2 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod]
        public string[] GetCarMakeList(string prefixText, int count)
        {
            string sql = "Select DISTINCT Make from Car_Makes_Models Where Make LIKE @prefixText";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, "Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=CDC;Integrated Security=True");
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = prefixText + "%";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                items.SetValue(dr["Make"].ToString(), i);
                i++;
            }
            return items;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot for the life of me get it to work. When I try running the Web Service through a web browser and entering in values, it retrieves the required info just right and returns them as an array of strings. But it just seems like the AutoCompleteExtender is just not firing.

It is worth noting that the first time I tried it, it worked. Then after any subsequent tries it didn't. I am dumbstruck. And if I run it with IE I get the know error message about using the AJAX ScriptManager (Which I already am using) and 4.0 Scripts. I have the AJAX toolkit properly installed and referenced and yes it does support .NET v4.5 which is my Target Framework.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect the ajax logs from firebug's network console or may be fiddler ? (so you may know the issue is in background process or client-side js or else..)

Comment: @Harsh I have used both Fiddler and Firebug and from the console I get the 2 errors:
`Error: AjaxControlToolkit requires ASP.NET Ajax 4.0 scripts. Ensure the correct version of the scripts are referenced. If you are using an ASP.NET ScriptManager, switch to the ToolkitScriptManager in AjaxControlToolkit.dll.`

AND

`TypeError: Sys.Extended is undefined`
And as you can see I AM using the AJAX ToolKitScriptManager. I have it correctly referenced and all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing the ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll in your bin folder with the latest version?  I have found that sometimes VS overwrites the dll with a reference copy on occasion.

Comment: Yes I have tried that. Manually downloading the zip file and replacing it. I also tried reinstalling the AjaxToolkit from NuGet and from the console, and even installing the previous version 4.1.60623 (Current: 4.1.60919)
Still getting the errors mentioned above in my comment.

Comment: Ahhh.. same problem this side!! so frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code snippet, use `ScriptManager` instead of `ToolkitScriptManager`

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.Common.Common.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="AjaxControlToolkit.ExtenderBase.BaseScripts.js" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />
            </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

In reference to [asp.net forum](http://forums.asp.net/t/1228497.aspx)

Also check the version of `AjaxControlToolkit.dll`, it should be `3.5` or more and not `1.0`

Check my answer over [AjaxControlToolkit.CommonToolkitScripts error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5192453/468718) which solved the problem for other user with similar kind of issue in different .NET framework scenerio.

Comment: I tried that and followed your link and the info you gave to other users. I appreciate your help however it is not working. I get the same error the other user got in your referenced article. And you direct him that it is 3.5 scripts. Well I am using 4.5 and I can't seem to solve it. I researched trying to find the 4.5 replacement for those scripts but I am still not able to figure it out. If you can help me anymore that would be great.

Comment: I noticed something when I get the error page. At the bottom it is showing this message:
`Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18010 `
Could it be that IIS is running it under 4.0? Although I checked IIS application pools and it has v4.5 listed but with .NET Framwork Version as `v4.0` meaning verion `v4.0.30319`
Tries to change that have ended up with me frustrated as it doesn't seem changeable, and on some posts I've found it says that its ok and it should be that.

Comment: Just a thought from me.. Looking at the time you have been spending over 'ACT Autocomplete', why don't you give a try to jquery autocomplete a once.. I believe that anything that works is good for you and your superiors and also jquery is more rich library than 'ACT' :D

Comment: You know what I will. I did give it a try once after this didn't work and that also was not working. But maybe I didn't give it enough time or effort as I did ACT. I'll try it and let you know Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use AjaxControlToolkit **version 4.1.60919** it'll work correctlly